# Script hangs on slackware 15.0

Tags: bash, slackware, mailx, aide

I wrote the following simple script to automatically run aide and email the result.

```
nice -n 12 aide -C 
mailx -s "AIDE Report: ${HOST}" ${ADMIN}@${SMTP} < /var/log/aide.log
exit
```

It works as expected on rhel7, rhel8, & slackware 14.2.  However, it doesn't work as expected on slackware 15.0.  That is, it runs and sends the email; but, it then hangs.  I have to do a Ctrl-C to get the CLI prompt back.

The program combinations where it works are:
bash-4.2.46, mailx-12.5.7, aide-0.15.1
bash-4.4.20, mailx-12.5.7, aide-0.16
bash-4.3.48, mailx-12.5.7, aide-0.17.3

The program versions where it hangs is:
bash-5.1.16, mailx-14.9.23, aide-0.17.3

I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting this.

**UPDATE:**  This is getting more confusing.

When I run the script directly `/root/bin/AideCheck.sh` in either the foreground or background, it "hangs" and I have to Ctrl-C to get the CLI prompt back.

When I used Morton's suggestion of using "bash -x" it runs "as expected" in the foreground.  The output:

```
root@loki:~/bin# bash -x /root/bin/AideCheck.sh
+ ADMIN=sysadmin
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ DATE=20220928
+ DOMAIN=aufait.net
++ hostname -f
+ HOST=loki.aufait.net
+ SMTP=smtp.aufait.net
+ nice -n 12 aide -C

< output of aide snipped >

+ echo loki.aufait.net sysadmin@smtp.aufait.net
loki.aufait.net sysadmin@smtp.aufait.net
+ mailx -s 'AIDE Report: loki.aufait.net' sysadmin@smtp.aufait.net
+ exit
root@loki:~/bin#
```

However, when I run it in the background, it "hangs".  The output:

```
root@loki:~/bin# bash -x /root/bin/AideCheck.sh &
[1] 16846
root@loki:~/bin# + ADMIN=sysadmin
++ date +%Y%m%d
+ DATE=20220928
+ DOMAIN=aufait.net
++ hostname -f
+ HOST=loki.aufait.net
+ SMTP=smtp.aufait.net
+ nice -n 12 aide -C

< output of aide snipped >

+ echo loki.aufait.net sysadmin@smtp.aufait.net
loki.aufait.net sysadmin@smtp.aufait.net
+ mailx -s 'AIDE Report: loki.aufait.net' sysadmin@smtp.aufait.net
^M^M^C^C

[1]+  Stopped                 bash -x /root/bin/AideCheck.sh
root@loki:~/bin# jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 bash -x /root/bin/AideCheck.sh
root@loki:~/bin# fg 1
bash -x /root/bin/AideCheck.sh
+ exit
```

The ^M & ^C is from me hitting the 'enter' key & Ctrl-C.

In all cases, it sends the email.  What is the difference between running it in the background and foreground?

Comment: run it using `bash -x script` to debug but first copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net to fix the issues it tells you about and read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and fix your all-caps variable names.

Comment: @ed RE variable capitalization.  All the books that had bash script examples always capitalized the variables.  As someone said, it doesn't matter how you do it as long as you are consistant.

Comment: If you run `aide` in the background from the terminal, does it update the logfile you're trying to send as expected? If you run your script in the background, but redirect `/dev/null` _into_ the script (`bash -x /root/bin/AideCheck.sh </dev/null &`), does it make it work? If so, there is something that detects that the application is not attached to a terminal, and it assumes it needs to read data from standard input. Being unfamiliar with `aide`, I don't know whether it is expected to behave differently with and without an attached terminal.

Comment: `aide` apparently has a configuration file, which you are not showing. I'm not sure it's important though as I don't know the software at all.

Comment: @Garnet you're reading the wrong books and whoever said "it doesn't matter how you do it as long as you are consistant." doesn't understand the issues. Those who use all upper case variable names run the risk of creating cryptic errors when they clash with environment variables and it makes your code harder to read as then no-one can tell environment variables from other variables and when you intended to use an environment variable vs when you accidentally clashed with one.

Comment: @kusalananda aide is a file integrity checker similar to tripwire.  The only configuration options are where the file hashes are located, where to write the output, and which files to check.  No user input is required when running.  No user input required.  It was meant to be run in cron jobs.

Comment: @Kusalananda the ```< /dev/null``` redirection did not make any difference.

Comment: In general I found, that if a process in the background hangs, it expects a terminal somehow. Can you try `(cat /var/log/aide.log ; echo q ) | mailx .....`? or `fg` the job and an `^D` (not the `^C)?